# Replicate R plot() of Spatial Points Dataframe RGB values with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgb

I'm attempting to use ggplot to replicate a plot() of a spatial points data frame, which has rgb values to plot a raster of colors.  This problem seems so basic and I use ggplot regularly...any help would be greatly appreciated.

The spatial points data frame `amre_map` appears as follows:

```
> head(amre_map)
  red green blue
1 150    61  152
2 248    55   83
3 220    66   61
4 118   127   73
5 124   126   71
6 188    74   71

> class(amre_map)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> dim(amre_map)
[1] 100000      3
```

The R code for the plot I want to replicate is:

```
> par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
> plot(amre_map,col=rgb(r,g,b,max=255),pch=15)
> lines(breeding.shp)
```

[image: gf_plot]

The closest ggplot code I've gotten to work is below.  I converted `amre_map.df` to a data frame:

```
> ggplot(amre_map.df, aes(x=x, y=y,fill = rgb(red,green,blue, maxColorValue = 255))) + 
theme_bw() +
geom_tile() + 
coord_equal() + 
scale_fill_identity()
```

[image: gf_ggplot]

I also tried `geom_raster()` but the computer struggled on it for a long time without producing anything except a warning

```
> ggplot() +
geom_raster(data = amre_map.df, 
  aes(x = x, y = y, fill = rgb(red, green ,blue, maxColorValue = 255)

Warning messages:
1: In f(...) :
Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you have to replicate that same plot? Because the most natural approach to plot points is as points, so you could try to improve that plot. But if you hace to do it, then two things come to my mind. The first one is if the original plot is derived from a spatial interpolation such as kriging. Please notice that the original plot is a raster or some kind of gird. The second thought then if you want to creare a grid, count how many point fall on each grid and then plot the grid. In the latter case you may need information about the original grid as well.

Comment: No, I don't necessarily need to replicate it exactly.  I tried geom_points() but I think it's too many points for it to work.  It just made the computer chug away for a long time

Comment: try to make te points a little bit bigger with the **size** argument and then add some transparency with the **alpha** argument.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it but I think 100,000 points is too many for geom_point, it doesn't produce a result in a reasonable amount of time

Comment: Try the [tmap](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap) library.